# Obsctacle avoidance for a drone - which approach should I take?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, realsense

This is my first post here, so hello everyone.

I am working on a project that involves writing a program in c++ or python that will detect obstacles and will be used for AR.Drone 2.0. However, I don't know which approach should I take.

Initially, I was adviced to use opencv and optocal flow. I've found some videos and papers about it and one way is that: divide every frame from AR.Drone's camera on 2 (left/right side) or 4 (additionally up and bottom) and calculate optical flow for each part. Then, fly in the direction where the optical flow is less.

However I have some doubts about it:

1)Which method of optical flow calculation should I use? I know that in opencv there are provided methods for calculating both dense or sparse optical flow. Which one should I choose in this application? Won't dense optical flow be too slow to meet real-time requirements?

2)I guess that in time when UAV moves left-right or up-down I'll get some "fake" vectors caused by the movement of a drone and not because of the looming obstacle. How to prevent this?

Another solution I was told about a method shown [here](https://github.com/tgarc/flownav) (link for paper in description) and someone who implemented it [github link](https://github.com/tgarc/flownav) however the author admitted that he "never get obstacle detection working properly on the drone".

Another option I was told about is attaching a realsense camera to a drone and extract an information about the obstacle somehow using it.

So, my question is - which path should I take? Or is there some other method to do this that  will work for application I described and is relatively easy to implement?

Thanks in advance for every reply.

Comment: What payload can your drone carry (sensor + computer, etc.)?

Comment: In addition to @Rethunk question, what type of obstacles are you trying to avoid? Just large ones? Man-made?

Comment: @Jello I think that result like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QQCGLKuUxc would be nice. However I am open to implement a system that would work for another type of obstacles. What do you mean by 'large ones' and man made?
I know that complex and unflawed system of obstacle avoidance is impossible to implement only with one regular camera.  

One thing I haven't written - all calculations will be done on laptop - not unit inside drone (project is based on Robot Operating System)

Comment: @Rethunk My drone is Parrot AR.Drone 2.0 so I guess it can carry not much more than mentioned realsense or something of similar weight.

Comment: @anicet95 I didn't know what kind of environment you would be flying in. If you are doing an in doors, completely controlled experiment, then i would say you could mirror what they did in that video. Which appears to be object detection/pattern recognition of the control image taped to the post. Optical flow can be unreliable when dealing with organic environments like vegetation which is why I asked about the obstacle being man made. So you will be streaming the video to a groundstation, correct?

Comment: @Jello I wanted to post this youtube link in first post but I pasted link to github twice by mistake. This video is related to a method I mentioned before that seems impossible to implement (discussion in issues). Yes, I will be streaming it to a laptop. I have another idea - calculate dense optical flow for left and right part of every frame, sum up the magnitudes of vectors and if ratio of average magnitude of one side to another is greater than x (set after experiments) then detect a collision. Now I try to adjust code doing it. I don't know if there is any chance it will work out right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the scope of your project, whether or not this is academic or professional, but my recommendation would be to use object detection of a control image with the camera facing directly forward on the drone. if the object is detected, you can estimate it's distance from your drone based on it's size. Since it is a control image it should have a constant size and you should record how many pixels across that is at various distances from your camera. This way you can build up a model. Once you know how far away the object is you can determine if it is an obstacle or not.

Once the detection becomes large enough, determine if it is in the flight path. Then you move the drone such that the coordinates of the detection box are no longer in your flight path.

For the detection, you can either use [Google's detection api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) which comes with a number of solid detectors/classifiers, or if you are looking to add a layer of depth to the project you can train your own. [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/) is a great place to start. And if you are feeling extra scientific you can dive right into [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry for late answering. Finally, I decided to try to go another path first and now I am testing it, however I would like to thank you very much for your interest in my problem. Your solution sounds interesting but it is something totally new for me and I might have not enough time to implement it. But once again - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the open source project https://github.com/generalized-intelligence/GAAS
It uses stereo camera and SLAM to detect obstacles.